# Logic Gates w/ Binary

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to use Logic Gates with true false statements like AND / OR / XOR. My console keeps telling me that there is an issue with line 35 and like 14, but I don't see any errors.

```js
var or;
var and;
var xor;
var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;

function truefalse(){
  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }if else (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }if else (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <button onclick = "trueFalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
<br>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it say the issue is?  Which is line 35? You don't need the `<script>` tags in a code snippet - I've removed them.  Also, you have a mismatch between `trueFalse` and `truefalse` - is that the issue you're seeing? Also it's `else if`, not `if else`.

Comment: There aren't 35 lines.

Comment: `<input>` tag is self-closing.  What you're doing is bad syntax.

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: trueFalse is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 24,
  "colno": 35
}
This is the Exception he gets

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt This is clearly not the only error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function truefalse(){
  var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
  var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;

  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <button onclick = "trueFalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
<br>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
```

It's `else if`, not `if else`.

`<h1>` doesn't go in `<head>`. You probably meant `<title>`.

The `else if`s that you use aren't necessary since you use `||`. They'd only be necessary in that situation if you'd used `&&` instead.

You need to reinitialize `binary` and `binarytwo` each time. Accessing `.value` only gives you what it was at the time it was accessed. Since you accessed it once when the script first runs, you're only ever getting its initial value and never what the user enters later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got your `if`s and `else`es the wrong way round in here:

```
if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
}if else (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
}if else (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
}else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
}
```

It should be `else if (..)`

---

```
<button onclick = "trueFalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
```

Should be..

```
<button onclick = "truefalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
```

to match `function truefalse()`

---

Input tags are self closing which means you don't need `</input>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reaccess the variables inside of the `trueFalse` function.

You also had typos:

- its `else if` not `if else`
- the casing of the function name didn't match

```js
var or;
var and;
var xor;


function trueFalse(){
  // Look here.
  var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
  var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;
  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here</input>
  <br>
  <button onclick = "trueFalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
<br>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition){
     // ...
} else if (condition2){
     // ...
} else {
     // ...
}
```

There is no such thing as `if else`.